# Copying recursively files with spaces

Tags: command-line, cp

At the moment I have a set of files of the form of:

```
/dir one/a picture.jpg
/dir two/some picture.jpg
```

What I want to do is copy and change the end to `-fanart.jpg` to the filename to:

```
/dir one/a picture.jpg
        /a picture-fanart.jpg
/dir two/some picture.jpg
        /some picture-fanart.jpg
```

I've managed to get it working for the situation where there are no spaces:

```
% for i in `find . -name "*.jpg"`; do cp $i "${i%.*}"-fanart.jpg ;done;
```

but I to get it working where there are spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command substitution (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`) is split on newline, tab and space character (not only newline), and filename generation (globbing) is performed on each word resulting of that splitting. That's the *split+glob* operator. You could improve things by setting `$IFS` to newline and disable globbing, but here, best is to write it the proper way:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    cp "$i" "${i%.*}-fanart.jpg"
  done' sh {} +
```

You could also use `pax` for that:

```
pax -rws'/\.jpg$/-fanart&/' -s'/.*//' . .
```

Or `zsh`'s zmv:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -QC '(**/)(*)(.jpg)(D.)' '$1$2-fanart$3'
```

Answer (score 2):

Word expansion is performed during the expansion of unquoted command substitutions, which is why this does not work.

If you have bash4+, just use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.jpg; do
    cp -- "$file" "${file%.*}-fanart.jpg"
done
```

Comment: That assumes there is no symlink to directories in there. If you're going to use `**/` best is to use `zsh` or `ksh93` which don't have the problem.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Traversing symlinks to directories is not universally undesirable (although I agree, it is not ideal in many situations). I am still pushing for there to be an option to disable recursion in 4.3.

Comment: I agree make `**/` not follow (like in `zsh`, `ksh93` or `tcsh`) and make the "following symlinks" an option would be better. However, options a la `shglob` are nice but sometimes add more issues than they solve. It's better to enable the _unexpected_ behaviour _per-glob_ than globally. Using `***/` like in `zsh` or `tcsh` would be better. Having globbing qualifiers to enable the `noglob`, `nullglob`, `nocaseglob`, `failglob`... _per-glob_ like in `zsh` would also be a lot better.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Considering how long bash 4 has been out now, I highly doubt that Chet would be willing to break backwards compatibility. `***` would be reasonable, otherwise.

Comment: Chet has done far worse backwards compatibility breaking before (for instance to align `=~` with `ksh93`'s). Changing `**/` is more likely to fix scripts than break them. GNU `grep` has broken a (decade long) backward compatibility by making `-r` stop follow symlinks at some point.